# Disable / Enable window using WinApi Function EnableWindow

Tags: vb.net, winapi

When trying to disable windows, the child windows are not disabled. Only the main window of the process is deactivated. Is it also possible to deactivate all the windows coupled to the main window?

The user should have no options to make any input or click the buttons in the application. After the elements are deactivated, a info message pop up. The application is closed immediately because it is an old session. The user should not have the opportunity to work with an old version.

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Private Shared Function EnableWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, bEnable As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function  

For Each processId As Integer In _processIds
    Dim currentProcess As Process = Process.GetProcessById(processId)
    EnableWindow(currentProcess.MainWindowHandle, False)
Next
```

Comment: They are disabled in terms of input, are you talking about how they should change color when disabled?

Comment: I guess this question essentially hinges on a misunderstanding of what enabled means in Windows

Comment: Maybe explain what is that you actually want to achieve. Disabling all the windowed processes in the System seems somewhat extreme. After that, what should happen?

Comment: Why not put the pop-up message(use modal window) before it? So that you don't need to care about disable all child windows.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT 
Unfortunately that does not help me. There are several applications open that I have to close. The user may not have the opportunity to make entries.

Comment: According to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow) *If a window is already disabled, its child windows are implicitly disabled*. Are these windows real relationships of parent&child?